# Counting 2 fields while grouping by 1

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
Agent  Call  Success
John  |  X  | Yes |
John  |  X  | Yes |
John  |  X  | No  |
Jane  |  X  | Yes |
Jane  |  X  | No  |
Jane  |  X  | No  |
```

I have a table similar to this. I am trying to find a way to get a select query to extract the data like this

```
Agent Calls  Failed
John |  3  |   1
Jane |  3  |   2
```

I tried a count but I couldn't do both of them while grouping by Agent.

Comment: should post your code so we could help fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MS Access the Query would be,

```
SELECT tmpTbl.Agent, 
       Count(tmpTbl.Calls) AS CountOfCalls, 
       Sum(IIf([tmpTbl].[Success]="No",1,0)) AS Failed
FROM tmpTbl
GROUP BY tmpTbl.Agent;
```

The code by @Sadikhasan might work on SQL not on Access.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed.

Comment: Glad you have it sorted ! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Agent,
  COUNT(CALL) AS CallS,
  SUM(IF(Success="NO"),1,0) AS Failed
FROM my_table
GROUP BY Agent
```

Comment: The table returns all the fields I want perfectly with the exception of the Count of "Success. It is giving me the entire count regardless of "YES" or "NO"

Comment: My answer is not as per your expected output?

Comment: It was giving the desired output however it was counting the field Success regardless of its value. So it would show all calls as failed no matter the value.

Comment: If you give proper expected output and explaination then get desired answer anyway.

Comment: @Sadikhasan, I think Chuck has got his answer. Please refer to the other answer I have provided.

Comment: Ok Thanks I checked it

Comment: This would be fixed by changing it from `COUNT(Success="NO") AS Failed` to `SUM(Success="NO") AS Failed` .